# Let $R$ be a relation on a set $A$. Show that if $R \circ R \subseteq R$, then $R$ is transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

On a recent quiz I encountered the problem: Let $R$ be a relation on a set $A$. Show that  if $R \circ R \subseteq R$, then $R$ is transitive.

I gave the following answer:

Assuming $R$ is a relation on a set $A$ and $R \circ R \subseteq R$.

Let (x,z) $\in R \circ R$ iff for some (x,y) $\in R$ and (y,z) $\in R$.

Since $R \circ R \subseteq R$ then (x,z) $\in R$, therefore R is transitive because x$R$y, y$R$z and x$R$z.

However this proof was marked as wrong because I started the proof incorrectly. Could someone please explain to me why the assumption is invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$ and from these two statements show that $(x,z) \in R$. This shows transitivity.

Now, the two statements show that indeed $(x,z) \in R \circ R$ by definition (using $y$ as intermediate).

We have the assumption that $R \circ R \subseteq R$, so we know that $(x,z) \in R$ as required, as $(x,z)$ is in the left hand side.

Answer (score 3):

Your formulation is incorrect. You're doing the right steps, but you're writing them down wrong, the logical meaning of what you write is different from what you mean. Here's proper formulation:

Let $R$ be a relation on $A$ such that $R \circ R \subseteq R$.

Let $x, y, z \in A$ such that $(x, y), (y, z) \in R$. By definition of $R \circ R$, it follows that $(x, z) \in R \circ R$.

Now $R\circ R \subseteq R$, so $(x, z) \in R$. This shows transitivity.

Answer (score 2):

The relation is transitive when

> for all $x,y,z\in A$, if $x\mathrel{R}y$ and $y\mathrel{R}z$, then $x\mathrel{R}z$.

Thus you have to start with $x,y,z\in A$, such that $x\mathrel{R}y$ and $y\mathrel{R}z$, and prove that $x\mathrel{R}z$.

Now, $x\mathrel{R}y$ and $y\mathrel{R}z$ implies $(x,z)\in R\circ R$; since $R\circ R\subseteq R$, we can deduce that $(x,z)\in R$, that is,
$$
x\mathrel{R}z
$$
as required.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to start with with given elements $x, y, z \in A: xRy, yRz$. Now you have to show that $xRz$. However you started with an elements $x, z\in A: (x, z) \in R\circ R$, which is the wrong antecedent for the implication you want to prove.

BS